# OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:715: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'imwrite'

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I'm new to Python and I have some issues that I don't understand.

**My code**

```py
import cv2

if not os.path.exists('hasilcrop'):
  os.makedirs('hasilcrop')
angka= 10
for a in range(angka):
    image = cv2.imread("./image_frames/frame"+ str(a)+".png")
    cropped_image = image[600:1000, 10:1500]
    cv2.imwrite("./hasilcrop/crop"+str(a)+".png", cropped_image)
```

**The code returns:**

> OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:715: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'imwrite'

when I run this code, there is no error such empty file or something

```py
from datetime import timedelta
FPS = 24.0
angka= 10
for i in range(angka): 
    td = timedelta(seconds=(i / FPS))
    mmq = Image.open("./image_frames/frame"+ str(i)+".png")
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(mmq,lang = 'ind')
    print("isi dari "+str(td)+ ":" + text)
```

I'm very confused, what is wrong with my code?

Comment: The reason this is happening is that the `cv2.imread` statement returns `None`. This happened to me a few times before and always was due to that the file specified by the path did not exist.

Comment: Apparently, your `image` hasn't been read. Make sure that the images `frame0.png` till `frame9.png`  really exist in `image_frames` folder

Comment: yes,the output return to img.empty .but when i run another code that have same directory it's doesn't return such a file empty

Comment: Here's contents of my images_frame folder https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXIts.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turn out the error in my code is in the ***cropping image section***
the endY and endX it's to big so i decided to change like this

```
cropped_image = image[350:500, 100:780]
```